# Region of the plane by this function

Tags: calculus

[image]

I think that it has to into specific cases but I don't really know how many cases would there be, can someone explain it even if they dont sketch it

Comment: What does $[[x]]$ mean here?

Comment: greatest integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), the only way to sum two squares to $1$ is if one of the squares is $0$ while the other is $1$. Hence we have $4$ possibilities corresponding to distinct regions: $$([[x]],[[y]])\in\{(0,-1),(0,1),(-1,0),(1,0)\}$$

For (b), the only way to take a difference between two squares to get $3$ is if the first is $4$ and the second is $1$. Again this gives us $4$ regions:

$$([[x]],[[y]])\in\{(-2,-1),(-2,1),(2,-1),(2,1)\}$$

For (c), the only integers that satisfy $a^2=1$ are $-1$ and $1$. Hence we have
$$[[x+y]]\in\{-1,1\}$$
which means our regions are $1\le x+y<2$ and $-1\le x+y<0$.

For (d), we have $[[y]]=1-[[x]]$, so it consists of regions of the form 
$$([[x]],[[y]])\in\{(k,1-k)~|~k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$